# How to check if a radio button has been selected, if it has assign a value to variable

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writing a distance calculator for an assignment and for one of the requirements is to have the user select which units they want the distance is displayed. I'm using the haversine equation to work out the distance. The code what I have to check if the button has been selected is

```cs
private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MilesButton.Checked == true)
    {
        radius = 3956;
    }
}
```

It gives me the error  "The event can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=".
Is there a better way to check if the button has been selected? Also if i use the method `MilesButton.IsChecked` is gives another error "cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool' an explicit conversion exists(are you missing a cast?)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work for you

In the XAML file:

```
    <Grid>
        <RadioButton x:Name="MilesButton" Content="MilesButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="66,39,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="distance" Checked="RadioButton_Checked"/>
        <RadioButton Content="KilometreButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="66,59,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="distance" Checked="RadioButton_Checked"/>
    </Grid>
```

And the code behind

```
        private int radius = 0;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (MilesButton.IsChecked == true)
            {
                radius = 3956;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Checked` use `IsChecked` property:

```cs
private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MilesButton.IsChecked ?? false)
    {
            radius = 3956;
    }
}
```

Also you can use [`GetValueOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0(v=vs.110).aspx) method like this:

```
if (MilesButton.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault())
```

Comment: I tried to use the method IsChecked and it also gives me an error. I edited the question to show which error it gives.

Comment: Did you try GetValueOrDefault method?